# Database error "Unknown field" when trying to add contacts to a group from a report

Tags: civireport, groups, reports

- Created a report with some custom fields in it.
- The report show up correctly with the custom field used
- When I click on "Add Contacts to Group" and choose a group I see a blank page stating an error appeared. The error is `"Unknown column 'civicrm_value_kandidaturen__11_custom_134' in 'field list'"`

I do not know why this report causes this trouble as this function (adding contacts to a group from a report) as this funtion works with other reports properly even if this custom field is added to the report. It is not clear for me when the query runs which causes this issue (it is an select query starting with `SELECT DISTINCT contact_civireport.id AS addtogroup_contact_id` and is quite large so I am not sure if I should paste it in here). Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Which report is the base report?

Comment: I do not know - is there a way to find it out?